# alias/function with command line arguments

Tags: bash, python, django

I'm  tired of typing `manage.py startserver 10.211.55.4:4000`, so decided to make an alias for that. Only thing is: the port sometime changes. So I did this in bash profile:

```
function runserver() {
   python manage.py runserver 10.211.55.4:$1
}
```

But then when I call it: `runserver 3000`, it starts it, but immediately stops saying:

"Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to". However if I type the same thing right into command line it works with no complains.

Comment: Sanity check: do you run `bash --login` all the time? Function definitions should be in `.bashrc`, not `.bash_profile`, since `.bash_profile` is only read by login shells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along the lines of your original attempt, you could adjust that function to the following:

```
function runserver() {
    python manage.py runserver 10.211.55.4:$PORT
}
```

and then call it like so:

```
PORT=3000 runserver
```

Comment: Alternatively of course, you could always just whip up a quick bash or python script that takes your port argument, and stick it somewhere in your path.

Comment: That wouldn't make any difference apart from the less convenient syntax. The command that's executed in the end is exactly the same.

Comment: The trick is that his function definition is in his bash profile.  $1 here refers to arguments given to the .bash_profile, not the function itself.

Comment: This is wrong. `$1` in a function definition refers to the argument of the function.

Comment: I must admit you are correct, I was mistaken.  Given that, I see nothing incorrect with the original function definition as provided in the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually an error you get back from Python/Django when you feed it an IP address it can't bind to (one that isn't part of the system) as shown in a real, just-run example below:

```
$ python manage.py runserver 123.123.123.123:8000
Validating models...

0 errors found
June 03, 2014 - 22:36:58
Django version 1.5.7, using settings 'tv.settings'
Development server is running at http://123.123.123.123:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to.
```

So you either need to fix your IP address (look at the output of `ifconfig --all` to see what's available) or you just bind to all of them with:

```
function runserver() {
    python manage.py runserver 0:$1
}
```

The bash side of things is sound.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right.

I suspect that you're running into a networking issue in your testing, and the fact that the failed test used the function was a coincidence. When you close a TCP connection, the port remains in use for a small amount of time (30s), in case there were pending packets that were not yet received (packets may arrive out of order). This is the [`TIME_WAIT` state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337115/setting-time-wait-tcp). To allow a new server to restart immediately, [set the `SO_REUSEADDR` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t) with `setsockopt` (there's an example in the Python [`socket`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) documentation).

Comment: but why does it work when I type the same thing right to the console?

Answer (score 0):

We can make alias with group command `{ list; }` and here-string `<<<` redirection. The key goal is to redirect `stdin` to the command. There's a couple of ways presented below

```
alias runserver='{ xargs -I % python manage.py runserver 10.211.55.4:%;} <<<'

alias runserver='{ IFS= read -r port; python manage.py runserver 10.211.55.4:"$port";} <<<'

alias runserver='{ port=$(line); echo python manage.py runserver 10.211.55.4:"$port";} <<<'
```

Note the space after `{` and semicolon before `}` are required.